# SSD versus RAM (system cache)

Tags: memory, ssd

If I have 16gb of RAM and I never shutdown pc do I still need SSD (perfomance vise)?
My concern is will SSD help (significantly) with perfomance if I already have ~8GB cached RAM for OS and apps.

Comment: They are different technologies. RAM is volatile (which means when you turn off your computer everything in it will cease to exist) while an SSD isn't volatile and as such you use it to store your OS and several other files. Putting it bluntly, you need somewhere to put your OS on, somewhere that will never (or at least for a very long time) lose its files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need is a term that can't really be used here, because you never `need` an SSD.

But memory will only do so much. Files are still being read and written to and from your harddrive, and windows likes to put lots of unuseful stuff in memory the more memory is available, so you will still have a swapfile. I have 12 GB Ram in my pc and I seriously benefit from having my SSD too.

If you were to have 64 gig of RAM, of which you created 32 gig ramdrive, and using a script at boot copy your programs on it so they run fast and then never shutdown the pc, the OS itself would still be located on a slow drive thus there is always room for improvement. So yes, an SSD will always help performancewise. RAM is more used for when you copy temporary stuff, such as images in memory for displaying it on the screen. If you have firefox open with lots of pages, all those pages with images will be in your memory too. (just to give an example)

Comment: Thanks :) ssd will bring improved perfomance. Now, I only need to buy best buy ssd :)